# How to show username when we speak though a discord bot

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

```
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.channel.id == "1012047542462185572"){
    var messageContent = message.content;
    client.channels.cache.get('1012048291111903292').send(messageContent)
  }
});
```

This code can only send a message from a channel to another though a bot but it's only the bot speaking, I want to add which user is speaking. How can i implement this?

Comment: `message.author.username` for the username, `message.member.displayName` for the name  the server member has. You can do something like `\`${message.member.displayName}: ${messageContent}\``

Comment: @Elitezen you should write this as an answer before someone else does!

Comment: It says
"SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: If i also want to display images, how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.channel.id == "1012047542462185572") {
        const { content, member, author } = message
        const channel = await client.channels.fetch('1012048291111903292')
        // for nickname:        
        const str = `**${member.displayName}:**\n${content}`
        // for username and tag 
        const str = `**${author.tag}:**\n${content}`
        // you may only use one of these. when you 
        // adapt it to your own code, remove one of
        // these "str", keep the one you want
        channel.send({ content: str })

  }
})
```

Comment: And if i want to display images too, how can i do it?